# Keeping track of specific people and topics

Tags: feature-request

How can I follow questions and answers for future reference?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to follow a specific topic you can use the `Interesting Tag` option. This feature will highlight all the question containning the tag you want to follow when they are displayed. This is usefull for spotting faster question about the topic you want to follow.

Additionnally, if you want to see the recent question containning the tag you want to follow you can use the search. For example, if I want to see the most recent question about php, [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest) will show them to me.

If you want to follow up a specific question, you can add that question in your favorite by clicking on the star. Everytime new answer will be posted, you will be notified and you can also access the list of your favorite question in your profile in the tab `Favorites`.

If you want to follow up someone in particular, you can view their recent activity in the tab `Activity` in their profile.